# Android manifest file out of sync

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest, adt

I have this weird problem with my android project in eclipse. When the workspace is built and I want to launch my code on a device (it doesnt matter if it is an AVD or a physical phone) after I click on the launch icon a got the following message on the "Problems" tab:

```
Description           Resource              Path        Location    Type
File is Out of sync   AndroidManifest.xml   /myproject  line 1      Android ADT Problem
```

Before I hit the launch button there is absolutelly no problem with my project, just in build time. I use a script in the prebuild process to update some version info in my project (so in manifest too) but formerly I didnt had problem with this either.
I googled it too but didn1t find any answer for this weird problem...

Comment: did you modified the manifest file from outside eclipse ?

Comment: No. The only thing it could modified the manifest is the script I mentioned.

Comment: try enabling auto refresh 
Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh Automatically (Refresh using native hooks or polling in newer builds) and see if it works

Comment: Still got the problem... I tried to check "Save automatically vbefore build" option too but same result.

Comment: I usually experienced this problem since I'm working on the same project from different PCs (home and work). Everytime I pull from my repository this happens.  Either you refresh your proect (Eclipse) or just run the application (sometimes this works for me)

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes when I change the project properties this error appears. You can do a `Project>Clean` and that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try selecting your project in the Package Explorer view, then pressing F5 (or right-click then choose Refresh)

This usually sorts out any "File is out of sync" problems

Comment: Sorry I didnt mentioned it in my question but tried this too. I think something goes wrong ater the prebuild process. So until that point everything seems OK with the project.